# Proceeding to an exception page after save new category

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.0, save

When I save new category, I proceed to exception page.

> exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with
> message 'Can't create directory
> /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/.'
> in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:103 Stack
> trace:
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> 1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> 2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Catalog...') 3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19):
> ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Catalog...') 4
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> 5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(71):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> 6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Catalog...',
> Array) 7
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Indexer/ActionFactory.php(35):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Catalog...',
> Array)  and more...#0

What is the problem? And how can I resolve it?
I use Magento ver. 2.0.0

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R 755 var pub` and check once

Comment: I solved this problem with your advice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var` folder does not have the right permissions.

I suggest you follow the official documentation to set the right permissions on your Magento instance: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your permissions. I believe this is a common issue for new setups. From root, run the below to amend permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Then clear your cache:

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*
```

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: I don't think the documentation recommends 777

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply.
I solved this problem.
Thank you so much.